# Should I rethink my database design if I seem to need to store the column names of one table in another?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm very new to database design, and I've got a fairly tall order from a client with some very complex relationships in their data. What I'm trying to do is write logic for recommending products based on what conditions a customer has. However, there are some interesting filters that need to be applied depending on the values of various other bits of data. For example, some products are only for {men|women}, so depending on the value of say `customers.customer_gender` the product would not be recommended.

Of course, I could do this all in PHP, but it would be better if I could represent it in the database and just make them a form interface to it. That way they could customize and modify these relationships as they add new products without having to rehire me to customize the code! My issue, then, is inexperience. I don't clearly see how I should be representing this information in tables.

**EDIT 1 -- Attempt at an example**

Imagine you have the following tables:

Customer

```
id   name      gender
--   ----      ------
 1   Bob       male
 2   Mary      female
 3   Steve     male
```

Condition

```
id    name
--    ----
 1    Headaches
 2    Allergies
 3    Low Energy
```

Products

```
id    name              description
--    ----              -----------
 1    Product A         anti-allergy
 2    Product B         energy booster
 3    Product C         pain reliever
```

and some further tables using foreign keys to define relations among these, such as what products are recommended for what conditions (a two-column table connecting the product id and condition id), and what customers have what conditions.

Now, I have certain products that can only be recommended to men, for example. Or only to people who are not sensitive to caffeine. Or who have a certain condition at a certain severity (where severity is an additional column in the table linking customers and conditions containing an int value from 1-3). How do I go about representing these sorts of relationships ("recommend product X for condition Y except where expression Z") in pure database tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem a model like this:

[image: ERD]

There are two key elements that help you with your design issue.

1. Have tables that indicate the rules for when a product applies as well as when a product does not apply.
2. Include in the `CONDITION` table any situation which could be involved in either a pro or a con rule.

For example: Viagra is contraindicated for patients with the condition "has a uteris".

`CONDITION_SEVERITY` implies both that the patient has the condition and it also allows you to record a score on whatever kind of scale you need to use to say how bad it is.  You can use a similar severity score in the `INDICATIONS` and `CONTRAINDICATIONS` tables to say a product only applies when a condition is *at least this bad* or should not be used if a condition is *this bad or worse*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your title is a definite **yes**, this should never be necessary.  If you want to make an extensible list of conditions, you can define this in a static table structure.  Consider something like this.

1. Customers Table: id, name, etc
2. Products Table: id, product_name, etc
3. Attributes Table: id, age, sex, etc
4. Attribute Values Table: id, attribute_id (foreign key link to *attributes*), value
5. Customer Attributes Table: id, customer_id (FK to *customers*), attribute_id (FK to *attributes*)
6. Recommendations table: id, attribute_id (FK to *attributes*), attribute_value_id (FK to *attribute values*), product_id (FK to *products*)

Here #6 would be the core of you recommendation engine, linking given attributes to given products.

This is just an example, but my point is that you can create a clean, static database structure that is fully extensible; no need to resort to craziness like dynamic table and column names.

Comment: I'm not really talking about dynamic table and column names. I was considering a table that stored the static names of other tables and mapped a relationship to their value. For instance, for any condition, it could have a severity of 1-3. Well if you pulled all product_ids from the blocks table where cond_id was the condition you're checking and severity is the severity the customer incidated, you'd have a block. That sort of thing.

Comment: @palintropos I'm having a hard time following what you just posted.  What's a *condition*, and a *block*, and what does *severity* signify?

Comment: A condition is a property of customer, in this case a medical condition, e.g. "has headaches". Severity is their subjective ranking of the condition, mapped to an int 1-3. A block would be something like "customer has seizures and therefore cannot take product X".

Answer (score 0):

Consider this design:

**Tables**

- Users (UserID PK)
- Medication (MedicationID PK)
- Symptoms (SymptomID PK)
- Severity (SeverityID PK)
- Treatments (TreatmentID PK)

**Example Data**

Users

```
UserID    Username          
1         john.smith   
2         jane.doe
3         bob.jones
```

Medication

```
MedicationID    Name
1               Tylenol
2               Excedrin
3               Morphine
4               Midol
5               Tums
6               Pepto
7               Anzemet
```

Symptoms

```
SymptomID   Name          
1           Headache        
2           Cramps   
3           Vomiting       
4           Dizziness
```

Severity

```
SeverityID   Name 
1            Feels bad
2            Feels really bad
3            I want to die
```

Treatments

```
TreatmentID  SymptomID    SeverityID   MedicationID
1            1            1            1
2            1            2            2
3            1            3            3
4            2            1            1
5            2            2            4
6            2            3            2
7            3            1            5
8            3            2            6
9            3            3            7
```

Using the data above a `User` can come in and say, I have a headache (`SymptomID of 1`) with a severity level of `2`. That would suggest the medication `Excedrin`.

The Treatments table can suggest a medication based upon the Symptom and Severity.

```
SELECT m.Name AS MedicationName
      ,sy.Name AS SymptomName
      ,sev.Description AS SeverityDescription
FROM Treatments AS t
INNER JOIN Medication AS m
  ON t.MedicationID = m.MedicationID
INNER JOIN Symptoms AS sy
  ON t.SymptomID = sy.SymptomID
INNER JOIN Severity AS sev 
 ON t.SeverityID AS sev.SeverityID
```

Comment: I see what you mean, and translated to my project, I think my answer is I basically need to split up the "customers" table. It looks like, e.g., I don't need `customers.customer_gender` because gender could be the basis of a block condition. I really need something like a `customer_attributes` table, though perhaps I can come up with a more humanizing name. :P

Comment: I'm still not sure you're perceiving the issue clearly, though. Maybe I can re-explain it and you can help me reword my question. Basically you need to think medical not retail. For instance, towel is a bad example because I can't think of a reason not to give someone a towel. These relationships are like "Customer X cannot be recommended Product Y because they indicated they have Condition Z". A secondary example would be restricting a product to be for one gender only (i.e., don't recommend a men's product to a female customer).

Comment: Don't take the towel example so literally. Understand the relationship between the tables. UserSettings is a Many-to-Many table where each record is a setting for a User. A user can have multiple settings. A product also has a SettingID. Using this UserSettings table we can find out which Products apply to the user because of the Setttings. Don't read into the data, it was purely for the demo.

Comment: I updated my answer to something that fits your description a bit more. Try to understand the relationships between the tables and don't focus on the example data too much. Also pay attention to the query and see if what it returns is something that could help you. I think you need to focus more on writing out what your system needs.